# Why does mockito think my service is being called twice?

Tags: java, mockito, square-connect, square

I’m having trouble using mockito to verify the number of calls to a mocked method.

This is my **test**

```
@Mock
private SquareClient squareClient;

@Mock
private PaymentsApi paymentsApi;


@Test
public void testBlah() throws Exception {
    ...
    when(squareClient.getPaymentsApi().getPayment("p1")).thenReturn(VALID_PAYMENT_RESPONSE);

    sut.process(EXAMPLE_PAYLOAD);

    verify(squareClient).getPaymentsApi().getPayment("p1");     //<--------------error here
}
```

This is my **setup method**

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    ...
    when(squareClient.getPaymentsApi()).thenReturn(paymentsApi);
    ...
}
```

**Error**

> Wanted 1 time:
>   at com.squareup.square.SquareClient.getPaymentsApi(SquareClient.java:239)
>   But was 2 times:

That’s seems fine, but when you see the two calls come from. . **one is in the service**,

```
Payment payment = squareClient.getPaymentsApi().getPayment(paymentId).getPayment();
```

**And one in the test**. Why is this one here?

```
when(squareClient.getPaymentsApi().getPayment("p1")).thenReturn(VALID_PAYMENT_RESPONSE);
```

**My issues**

- Firstly, there should only be 1 call.
- Secondly, when I check for 2 times  `verify(squareClient, times(2)).getPayment("p1")` I get a **null pointer** because getPaymentsApi() is now null. Is this because the mock when() is not applying the second time?

Comment: is paymentsApi a mock too? or a real implementation? pls paste also your global variables to have more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply your when() statement in your @Test directly on the PaymentsApi object.

```
when(paymentsApi.getPayment("p1")).thenReturn(VALID_PAYMENT_RESPONSE);
```

You can't chain your method calls when using "when()".

Comment: I had no idea this was the case. I wish the errors would have given me better information, I was going round in circles with NPE, incorrect use of matcher error and number of wanted calls error. So thank you!